# show container on hover different container

Tags: html, show, hidden, onhover

i'm trying to show a hidden div while hovering over the logo of the page.

the website is: http://www.enbloc-magazin.de/

as i said i want to show a container (#snowflakesContainer, display: none;) while hovering ov the logo.

i used several scripts like:

```
$('#logo').hover(function() {
    $('#snowflakesContainer').toggle();
});
```

but nothing worked.

the css of the hidden container is:

```
#snowflakesContainer {
top: -553px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: none;
}
```

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console gives an error on your facebook jssdk code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null
```

on line 8:

```
 button    = container.getElementsByTagName( 'h1' )[0],
```

Try putting it below the page so you give your content the chance to load. 
Your javascript should work until there.